# Accuracy of COVID-19 Diagnostic Testing, particularly false-negatives

Tags: covid-19, united-states

I was surprised to hear Sanjay Gupta (CNN) say this morning (4/28/20) that there is significant disparity in the accuracy of the COVID-19 Diagnostic testing. He specifically mentioned that the inaccuracy is as high as 15% in reporting false-negatives.

Has the inaccuracy of the various tests for COVID-19 been publicly reported?

[NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2020/04/21/838794281/study-raises-questions-about-false-negatives-from-quick-covid-19-test) and [Others](https://www.livescience.com/covid19-coronavirus-tests-false-negatives.html) have reported, but what I am looking for is **clinical peer-reviewed reports or papers** that compare the various COVID-19 diagnostic tests for accuracy, particularly false-negatives.

Comment: This really needs more context.  A certain level of false-negative testing results is expected, when you test someone who's been infected but doesn't yet have a viral load high enough to detect.  This is why concluding that someone doesn't have the virus requires repeated negative results over a period of time.

Comment: I think we need an exact quote of what he said.

Comment: If so many are saying this, then you should have no problem finding a link to include in your question.

Comment: Need a link to what test they're referring to

Comment: And I think you're supposed to show some element of research in your question.

Comment: I think I found your [CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/28/health/coronavirus-antibody-tests-terrible/index.html) which you didn't link. It is talking about anti-bodies tests in re those 15%. Antibodies tests in the US have been [criticized before](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23192/why-are-novel-coronavirus-anitbody-tests-disparaged).

Comment: @Fizz, actually the article you linked never mentions Gupta, was originally broadcast six or seven hours after Gupta's interview in the morning. While I cannot find a video clip of Gupta's interview, to the best of my recollection he was addressing the inaccuracy of the COVID19 diagnostic tests rather than the antibody or antigen tests. Regardless, I mentioned Gupta as it was his interview that brought to my attention. The other citations I provided (NPR and others) were addressing the diagnostic tests rather than the antigen tests (separate but similar problems there).

Comment: @Fizz, but I take your point and will edit the question to be specific to the diagnostic tests (do you currently have COVID19 versus did you develop antigens)

Comment: @BobE Just a quick correction on terminology: you mean antibodies. PCR tests look for viral genetic material (RNA), antibody tests look for host-produced antibodies (using lab-produced antigens), antigen tests look for viral-produced antigens (proteins) using lab-produced antibodies.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks

Comment: No paper neither, but some weeks ago, Kekule (a German virologist and epidemiologist who is very prominently in the media right now) mentioned around 20 - 30 % false negative *PCR* tests due to difficulties with sampling (i.e. the swab not picking up the proper material) and that preferrably two swabs should be taken.